# Why is queen placement on the first turn disallowed?

Tags: hive

While official rules allow placing the queen on the very first turn, online play, community and tournaments prohibit it. Why? Does it provide an unfair advantage? Does it quickly lead to a draw? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [Wikipedia on Openings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hive_%28game%29#Openings),

> Bee - Spider - Spider (in a V formation with the bee at the point): This is an aggressive quick-strike opening that allows the player the fastest possible opportunity to move (on the third turn if necessary); the Spiders can thus quickly block the opponent's opening pieces. In addition, if the opponent answers with the same or a similar opening, it provides the best opportunity to force a draw if necessary as the Bees are adjacent. For this last reason, tournament rules forbid the placing of the Bee on the first move, as **this opening leads to a preponderance of draws**. Bee-Spider-Ant is a common variation very similar in its mechanics.

Emphasis mine.

[Bee - Spider - Spider](https://web.archive.org/web/20090413174743/http://www.hivemania.com/tips/index4.php)
[Bee - Spider - Ant](https://web.archive.org/web/20090413155542/http://www.hivemania.com/tips/index3.php)

Comment: I'm sure this is right, but it would be great if you could explain why in a bit more detail, and also if you had an example game as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @tttppp, The why is explained in great detail. (It's not my fault the reason is extremely simple.) I don't have an example since I've never played (though I own a copy and know the rules). Did you even try? The setup is described precisely.

Comment: I was expecting an explanation mentioning something like first/second player advantage. Why would both players be motivated to open with the bee if it so often leads to a draw? I can't think of another game where something is actually banned because it often leads to a draw. I also think an example game could help to illustrate the tactics, even if it's a fabricated example.

Comment: But if you disagree that these would make the answer better then don't worry about it-several people have already found your answer useful as it is, and maybe I'm just being slow! :-)

Comment: Yes, this is definitely useful, because I have not seen the Wikipedia articled before and this gave me basis for more research. Of course I also agree with @tttppp commment, because this particular quote is not very clear. In particular it is not clear why 2 spiders is a great opening given that it's the weakest piece. It's not clear how earliest opportunity to move is the third turn, in the example given the third turn is spider placement, not a move, so the wording looks plain wrong.

Comment: Re "Why would both players be motivated to open with the bee if it so often leads to a draw?" Because it would place the second player at a great disadvantage if he didn't.

Comment: Re "In particular it is not clear why 2 spiders is a great opening given that it's the weakest piece. It's not clear how earliest opportunity to move is the third turn," The OP didn't ask about strength of pieces and comparison of opening strategies.

Comment: @tttppp draws are preferable to a loss. This set up makes it likely that the first player will win if the second player does anything other than mimic the same moves - under those conditions, second player would rather draw than lose so this setup leads to almost nothing but draws. First player would make this move to guarantee not losing.

Answer (score 1):

Now when I have played a few dozen of games the answer is obvious. A piece is surrounded by 6 other pieces. When two bees are adjacent the 3 out of 6 surrounding spaces (one of each is the other bee) contribute to surrounding *both* of them. Because of this fact it's practically difficult (that is if your opponent's is decent) to surround your opponent bee and not surround your own at the same time.

Thus the draw is very likely if both opponents start with a bee.